# How does Broadcast Join work with more than 2 tables in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, query-optimization, performance-testing

All the articles only talk about joining 2 tables. What if my requirement is I want to join 4 tables and

Scenario a) 3 out of 4 tables are small, one is big
Scenario b) 2 out of 4 tables are small, two is big

How would Spark perform these? Will it use Broadcast join in scenario a? And what will be used in Scenario b? And why?

Comment: you can always extend the 2 table join scenario to multiple. start with basic 2 table broadcast join. now, think of this as a single df (which is now big because first df was big) and broadcast join it with third table. so, you end up broadcasting all the small dfs in the join. `df1.join(broadcast(df2, 'blah')).join(broadcast(df3, 'blah')).join(broadcast(df4, 'blah'))` or `df1.join(df2, 'blah').join(broadcast(df3, 'blah')).join(broadcast(df4, 'blah'))` - here `df2` is not a small df, so it wasn't broadcasted.

Comment: A gig question, u can try with .expain